# Arduino IDE for Emacs

Tags: ide

I am looking into setting up an Arduino IDE environment in Emacs (on both PC and OS X). I came across the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org) [ArduinoSupport](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ArduinoSupport) page, which has a good guide for Mac OS X and Linux, which is perfect.

However, I have a couple of questions:

- Does such a guide for Emacs on windows exist? I find it a bit of an
  odd omission from the page. Don't get me wrong, I don't like using
  Windows at all, but my Arduino will not connect to my Mac and so I am
  somewhat obliged to use Windows 7 to develop for it.
- Has anyone used or followed the above guide for Arduino on Emacs on Mac OS
  X? Is it a good guide, or are there better options out there?

I didn't know whether to ask this on the SE Arduino site, but it is more Emacs configuration related than Arduino.